# I have installed the google chrome but when i tried to lauch it on ubuntu 14.04 .it is not launching

Tags: 14.04

I have installed the google chrome on google-chrome-stable_current_amd64(2).deb
on ubuntu 14.04 but unable to launch it

Comment: What output you get if you try to launch it from Terminal?

Comment: Try opening the browser from another user. or you can use no sandbox method to run the browser as root.

Comment: A correctly installed Chrome would be found in: `/usr/bin/google-chrome-stable`.
In the start menu, for example the Whisker menu in Xubuntu, Chrome would be found in the tab Internet.
To see any (error) message during the start of Chrome, open a terminal and type: `/usr/bin/google-chrome-stable`.
If Chrome does NOT start, you will get the prompt back immediately in the open terminal. If it does start, you will NOT get the prompt back and obviously you should see the new Chrome window and an icon in the panel. If  Chrome does not start and you get an error, what is it?

Answer (score 0):

The filename `google-chrome-stable_current_amd64(2).deb` implies that you have downloaded `google-chrome-stable_current_amd64.deb` THREE times. You'll want to clean that up.

In a terminal window, find out which files are part of the package with the

```
dpkg --contents google-chrome-stable_current_amd64(2).deb
```

Find the file with the `.desktop` extension, and copy it to the directory where your other `.desktop` files are.

Find the directory where your other `.desktop` files are, by

```
locate -r '.desktop$' | grep -E $HOME/\.config
```

Mine are in `/home/w3/.config/cairo-dock/current_theme/launchers/`, but YMMV.